# How to use image or icon in Google meta descriptions?

Tags: html

Today, while I was searching in Google, I have seen a result with an image or icon. Does anyone have any ideas how can I do the same?
[image: search result with image/icon]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a ✅ emoji with the Unicode codepoint `U+2705`. Use it in your text description like any other emoji.

Comment: where can i find all available icons?

Comment: @untitled A good place for finding all emoji codepoints is https://emojipedia.org.